# Why I can't use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 to encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi

First of all, I'm completely new to cryptography and I just have basic knowledge about some encryption algorithms and how they work such as RSA, DES and so on.

I want to use [SubtleCrypto in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) to do some stuff including `signing, verifying, encrypting, decrypting` using RSA.

I'm just unable to produce a key pair for doing all of them; for example, below code works fine for generating a key pair to do *signing/verifying*:

```js
let keyPair = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: "SHA-512"
    },
    true,
    ['sign', 'verify']
  );
  
  keyPair.then((value)=>{
    console.log("worked properly.");
  })
  .catch((error)=>{console.log("Error:", error)})
```

But when I use above code to generate a key pair for *encrypting/decrypting* I'll get a DOMException(in browser) or SyntaxError(in snippet):

```js
let keyPair = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: "SHA-512"
    },
    true,
    ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
  );
  
  keyPair.then((value)=>{
    console.log("worked properly.");
  })
  .catch((error)=>{console.log("Error:", error)})
```

**Note:** I figured out RSA-OAEP behaves completely different, I means it works with encrypting/decrypting but gets stuck for signing/verifying and shows same error.

**Question:** Can you please provide me a link which explain the differences between these RSA variants and when should I use which one of them? I googled for it but I couldn't find anything and there is no explanation in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Sorry if my English wasn't very well.

Comment: Encryption/decryption and signing/verifying use different padding variants. This is explained in [RFC8017](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017). Encryption/decryption apply the older RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 and the more modern RSAES-OAEP. The corresponding counterparts in the signing/verifying context are RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSASSA-PSS. The WebCrypto API does not use RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 anymore since 2014, see [here](https://cryptosense.com/blog/choice-of-algorithms-in-the-w3c-crypto-api/).

Comment: @Topaco Thank you, I think that's why it results in this error.

Comment: Sure, in the context of encrypting/decrypting, you use a wrong padding, more precisely a padding for signing/verifying (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5). You should actually apply RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5, but this is no longer supported by the WebCrypto API. Thus, for encrypting/decrypting  with the WebCrypto API only RSAES-OAEP is available, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question which is:

> Question: Can you please provide me a link which explain the
> differences between these RSA variants and when should I use which one
> of them?

you can refer to this [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto#supported_algorithms), In bottom of ***Supported algorithms*** sections you can find a table which gives you a complete guidances about which algorithm is suitable for which operation.

The same algorithm couldn't be use for the all of operations because as [@Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045991/why-i-cant-use-rsassa-pkcs1-v1-5-to-encrypt-decrypt#comment113255039_64045991) below the question, they use different padding variants and so on:

> Encryption/decryption and signing/verifying use different padding
> variants. This is explained in [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017). Encryption/decryption apply
> the older RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 and the more modern RSAES-OAEP. The
> corresponding counterparts in the signing/verifying context are
> RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSASSA-PSS. The WebCrypto API does not use
> RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 anymore since 2014, see [here](https://cryptosense.com/blog/choice-of-algorithms-in-the-w3c-crypto-api/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems using those algorithms are kind of insecure for decryption nowadays.

But if you are still looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, then take a look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsencrypt

Update: It has not been proved is insecure to use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, but still is not recommendable.

Comment: You are saying they are insecure because of *Quantum Computing* or do you have another reason?

Comment: @milad There's been 25 years of attacks on PKCS#1 v1.5 implementations, look for Bleichenbacher attack and the 2 dozen variants of it.

Comment: @HubertKario: yes, still relevant. dotnet runtime is added this as a future milestone. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/97866

Comment: @codeandcloud I'm "tomato42" at github. I filed that issue... And in those "2 dozen variants" I included the [Marvin Attack](https://people.redhat.com/~hkario/marvin/) that I've discovered...